# How to find a perfect natural power number in vicinity of an arbitrary number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

If I pick a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n-x = a$ is a perfect natural power and $n+y= b$ is also a perfect natural power, then are there any methods or conditions to find $minimum(x,y),a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

A detailed solution and proof will be helpful.

Comment: See [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root)

Comment: If there is no restriction on $x$ and $y$ , the problem is trivial. Do you want to find the nearest squares ?

Comment: Yes the nearest ones

Comment: factoring works fine when $n$ is not a prime. Example: take $n=18=3*6$ so you can get the square $9$ and $36$ just by squaring $3^2=9$ and $6^2=36$. In the process you miss $16$ and $25$. You get those by finding the distance between $16$ and $25$. $25-16=9=3+6=2+7=1+8=4+5$. For $n=18$, you are limited to $x=2$ and $y=7$. That would be the minimum pairs $(16,25)$ and $(2,7)$. It gets harder if $n$ is the product of more than two primes but the process is the same. NDB suggestion is the fastest since once you get $18=s=4.24$, you only need to square $4$ to get $16$ and $4+1$ to get $25$.

Comment: It should be fairly trivial to see that you would just pick $z = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ and take $b=z^2$, $a=(z-1)^2$.  It's a bit unclear what you want to do if $n$ is already a square (depends on whether $\mathbb N$ includes $0$ or not).

Comment: Don't forget the gap prime is unbounded.